# mongoose filter nested array of object by value in the object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have orders schema like this

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  orderDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  products: { type: Array, default: [] }
});

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
module.exports = Order;
```

each order belongs to a specific customer (user), the user can purchase products from different sellers

so the products array is like this:

```
"products" : [
      {
        _id: "5f0289147b9b980f40d4f2e6",
        product: ObjectId("5f02879f7160ae0c2c203cdf"),
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        _id: "5f0289177b9b980f40d4f2e7",
        product: ObjectId("5f02879f7160ae0c2c203fgg"),
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
```

each product in the array is like this:

```
"product" : {
  _id: "5f02879f7160ae0c2c203cdf",
  name: "Some Car",
  category: "5f027c5ca1b94820b856c508",
  seller: "5f0276cf965f8c29e019a7f1" //seller can be different for each product
}
```

so what i wanna achieve is filter all the orders to get all the products sold by each seller.
like if i'm a seller and i'm logged in, i wanna get all the products sold by me in Order collection

i made a method where i get all the Orders collection and then populate the product in the products array and i filter all the data according to the condition i want and it works for me but it has 2 foreach, so the bigger the data get the slower the app will be, so is there an available way i can do it using only mongoose? or this is the best approach?

```
Order.find()
  .populate({ path: "products.product", model: "Product" })
  .exec((err, orders) => {
    if (err) res.status(400).json({ message: "Couldn't find user", err });
    else {
      let len = orders.length;
      let orderCurInx = 0;
      let productsToDeliver = [];

      orders.forEach(order => {
        ++orderCurInx;

        order.products.forEach(item => {
          if (item.product.seller == anySellerId) {
            productsToDeliver.push(product);
          }
        });
      });

      if (len == orderCurInx) {
        return res.status(200).json({ orders });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: So just to sum up - you want to get all orders, where in one of the products the seller-id matches a given seller-id?

Comment: instead of using find and then filtering up the element you can directly use aggreagation but to suggest the pipeline you must share the expected output

Comment: @harshitkohli yeah i think your method is the same as the one eol provided below, thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all the orders, where in one of the products the seller-id matches a given seller-id, you can use an aggregation with a combination of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)-pipelines:

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([{
            $lookup: {
                from: "products",
                localField: "products.product",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "mappedProducts"
            }
        }, {
            $match: {
                "mappedProducts.seller": ObjectId("5f04bae5698dc66950a991a3")
            }
        }
    ]);
```

How this works is that `$lookup` will search for the `foreignField` in the specified collection (`products` in that case) and add found `product`-documents to the `order`-document under a new array-property called `mappedProducts` (you can name this arbitrarily).

All that is left to do is to match those documents where the `seller`-id matches the given `id`.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it a give you a feedback :)

Comment: i really appreciate this method and ill look up aggregation and your code returns the whole order object as i want (with the order _id and orderDate) but it doesn't match seller id and returns all the products by different sellers in mappedProducts